# how can I stop a if condition?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need to make a physical button(like the push button) to stop the if condition from working, is that possible.

```
 void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(pushbutton);
  zhar = digitalRead(pushbutton1);


    if (val == LOW)
    {
      digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
      delay(900000);
      for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
        delay(400);
        digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
        delay(15000);
        digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
        delay(2000);
 
      }


    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your program logic and make loop() behave like a loop.

Your `if` should not take any time, then you don't have to interrupt it.

Get rid of all the `delay()` by understanding the BlinkWithoutDelay example.

Comment: I need your help one more time. can  I stop the loop and after a while I resume it to the point that I left it(progresses)

Comment: If loop runs fast and forever, the current state is stored in global (or static) variables. loop() won't STOP, but will check that currently there's nothing to do. (No state change). This programming paradigm is often called "Finite State Machine", because there can be many, but only a limited (finite) number of different states and all is about the change from one state to another.